# write mode in python not creating new file

Tags: python-3.x, file-io

- I was executing a program for creating a folder consisting multiplication table of 2 to 20, and for that, I am opening files of a folder that don't exist, and I am opening that with write mode, which ideally should create those folders and files if it doesn't exist but its giving error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tables/mul_2.txt'`
- Program:

```
   #multiplication folder
for i in range(2,21):
   with open(f"tables/mul_{i}.txt", 'w') as f:
       for j in range(1,11):
           f.write(f"{i}X{j}={i*j}")
```

- Python version: 3.8.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, the directories won't be automatically created for you if they don't already exist. You need to write additional code to actually create the directories. The code looks like this:

```
    import os

    ...

    # Create output directories if neccessary.
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname('tables/mul_2.txt'), exist_ok=True)
```

Comment: [An example.](https://github.com/r002/tetris_ctm_summary/blob/65fa44c3e52c2e3bae1dc33a5b0736d27b05334d/videoProcessor/statsExtractor.py#L136)  Note [that `outputFile` is the **entire** path](https://github.com/r002/tetris_ctm_summary/blob/65fa44c3e52c2e3bae1dc33a5b0736d27b05334d/videoProcessor/statsExtractor.py#L49), including the dir you're creating **_and_** the filename.